# HTMLPurifier not working on live server

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

HTMLPurifier works well on my localhost, but on live server it returns only plain text (strips off all tags) even though I have not used 'HTML.Allowed' config.

For example, for html "<b>foo</b>", it only returns 'foo'.

What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Test code:

```
require_once '/HTMLPurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$dirtyHTML = "<b>foo</b>";
$loop = 5;

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier( $config );

for( $i = 0; $i < $loop; $i++ )
    echo $purifier->purify( $dirtyHTML ) . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Please show us the codes to check.